# How to access the DialogFlow Node Js Client in Angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, dialogflow-es

I am newbie in Angular. I am trying to implement DialogFlow in an Angular app which has just a chat window. I am calling the *Dialogflow Detect Intent Api* in `dialogflow.service.ts` which is working fine. My problem is, I am not able to implement the token programmatically. Now I am changing the token manually when it expires.

I just saw [this](https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89) which shows implementation without token generation. But it is in node js. I don't know how the node js code will communicate with my angular app. Is there any other method which I can implement on my angular app which does token generation or doesn't need token generation.

I just want my angular app to communicate with DialogFlow V2 api with automated token generation from google cloud console.

**dialogflow.service.ts**

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DialogflowService {

  private userSession = new Date();
  private userSessiontoken = this.userSession.getTime();

  private baseURL: string = `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/projectID/agent/sessions/${this.userSessiontoken}:detectIntent`;
  private token: string = environment.token;

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  public getResponse(query: string){

    let data = {
      "queryInput": {
        "text": {
          "text": query,
          "languageCode": "en"
        }
      }
    }
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.baseURL}`, data, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .pipe(map(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json()
      }))
  }

  public getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.token}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', `application/json`);
    return headers;
  }
}
```

**message.service.ts**

```
import { Message } from '../models/message';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogflowService } from './dialogflow.service';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MessageService {

    private messages: Message[] = [];
    private messagesUpdated = new Subject<Message[]>();

    loader: boolean = false;
    loaderChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(private service: DialogflowService) { }

    addMessage(message: string) {

        const fullmessage: Message = {textContent:message,content: [],avatar: 'assets/images/user.png',self:true,action: 'nochip',timestamp: new Date()};
        this.messages.push(fullmessage)
        this.messagesUpdated.next([...this.messages]);

        var outputResult: string[] = [];
        var outputText: string;
        var action: string;
        var webhookStatus: any;
        var webhookStatusCode: string;

        this.service.getResponse(message).subscribe(res => {
            action = res.queryResult.action;

            if (res.queryResult['webhookStatus']) {
                webhookStatus = res.queryResult.webhookStatus
                if (webhookStatus['code']) {
                    webhookStatusCode = webhookStatus.code
                    console.log('status' + webhookStatusCode);
                }
            }

            outputText = res.queryResult.fulfillmentText;
            res.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages.forEach(element => {
              element.text.text.forEach(subelement => {
                outputResult.push(subelement)
              });
          });
        const serverMessage: Message = {textContent:outputText,content: [],avatar: 'assets/images/logo.png',self:false,action:'',timestamp: new Date()};
        this.messages.push(serverMessage)
        this.messagesUpdated.next([...this.messages]);

        if (webhookStatusCode) {
            return;
        }

        if (action == 'input.welcome') {
            return;
        }

        const userMessage: Message = {textContent:'',content: [],avatar: 'assets/images/user.png',self:true,action:'chip',timestamp: new Date()};
        this.messages.push(userMessage)
        this.messagesUpdated.next([...this.messages]);

        this.getLoader();

        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. I want to create a simple app with angular and dialogflow but it's difficult with dialogflow V2 because the documentation is not so helpfull.

I succeed in creating a dialogflow app with [this tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/group-chat-angular-dialogflow) if it can help you. But I have issue uploading it into my hosting service and it's too complicated for the purpose of my app.